# Looping and comparing times C#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backworker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        label1.Text = i.ToString();
        DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;

        label2.Text = d2.ToString();
    }
}
```

Friends i am working on comparing times between when the task of backworker finished,  like how much time it tooks to finish the loop task

but when i do it, i tried to put the Comparasion after loop but it tells me error because d2 not declared

so how can i solve that to compare and get the exact time that the loop took to finish the task of printing numbers

Comment: by declaring `d2` **outside** your loop?

Comment: Are you really declaring a variable inside a loop ? I guess performance is not any important for you at all then

Comment: @GuidoG: Performance is not the problem here. A declaration is handled at compile time and does not take any time by itself. Only the initialization of a variable takes up time. But since the OP is assigning it a value in the loop anyway, there is no performance advantage of moving the variable out of the loop. The problem is its scope.

Comment: @GuidoG: See here https://dotnetfiddle.net/IPU5V6. Select "View IL" from the "Tidy Up" drop-down. The declaration order of `i` and `d2` are different, but otherwise the compiler generates the same code. The assignment must be in the loop. This is the very purpose of this loop.

Answer (score 3):

I think this could work:

```
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
   ...
}
label2.Text = (DateTime.Now - d2).ToString();
```

A good way to measure times is to use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
   ...
}
label2.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `DateTime` is declared withing the loop and therefore its scope is limited to the loop body. You must declare it before, i.e., outside, the loop to make it available after the loop. But it is better to use a [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0) for this purpose.

Another problem is that you are attempting to access a Control (a Label) from another thread than the UI thread. You are not allowed to do this.

Fortunately the [BackgroundWorker Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-6.0) can "Talk" to the UI thread through the `ProgressChanged` event.

Setup the BackgroundWorker with:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backworker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backworker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Then declare another event handler which will automatically be called in the UI-thread:

```cs
private void Backworker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    var ts = (TimeSpan)e.UserState;
    label2.Text = ts.ToString(@"ss\.ff");
}
```

Now, change you worker to

```cs
private void Backworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        backworker.ReportProgress(i, stopWatch.Elapsed);
    }
    stopWatch.Stop();
    backworker.ReportProgress(100, stopWatch.Elapsed);
}
```

Note that I have introduced a `Thread.Sleep(100);` and have diminished the number of loops by 100. This is because otherwise the UI cannot display the progress that fast. In a real scenario you would replace `Thread.Sleep` by some useful work.